# Mezzanine on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, mezzanine

I'm trying to get a Mezzanine (Django) app up on Heroku. I have a custom theme in an app in the project.

I'm getting this error from the herokuapp site:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I'm getting this error from "heroku logs":

```
2014-03-01T03:16:46.703103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-03-01T03:16:52.887091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:48220`
2014-03-01T03:16:54.917679+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-03-01T03:16:54.917679+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" % tz)
2014-03-01T03:16:54.945927+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'collectstatic'
2014-03-01T03:16:54.945927+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-03-01T03:16:55.283913+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" % tz)
2014-03-01T03:16:55.283913+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-03-01T03:16:55.299183+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-03-01T03:16:55.299183+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-03-01T03:16:57.198274+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-03-01T03:16:57.211687+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-01T03:16:57.213010+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-03-01T03:17:02.491996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:48145`
2014-03-01T03:17:04.444781+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-03-01T03:17:04.472595+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-03-01T03:17:04.444781+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" % tz)
2014-03-01T03:17:04.472595+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'collectstatic'
2014-03-01T03:17:04.992615+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/conf.py:59: UserWarning: TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: Etc/UTC
2014-03-01T03:17:04.992615+00:00 app[web.1]:   warn("TIME_ZONE setting is not set, using closest match: %s" % tz)
2014-03-01T03:17:05.080366+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
2014-03-01T03:17:05.080366+00:00 app[web.1]: Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
2014-03-01T03:17:06.827562+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-03-01T03:17:06.842272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-01T03:17:08.397089+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=appname request_id=b2f6e7d5-9979-472d-b480-ca36a602f146 fwd="130.126.175.201" dyno= connect
= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Here's my installed apps var in settings.py (cc is my theme/app name):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    "cc",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.redirects",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "mezzanine.boot",
    "mezzanine.conf",
    "mezzanine.core",
    "mezzanine.generic",
    "mezzanine.blog",
    "mezzanine.forms",
    "mezzanine.pages",
    "mezzanine.galleries",
    "mezzanine.twitter",
    #"mezzanine.accounts",
    #"mezzanine.mobile",
    "gunicorn",
)
```

My requirements.txt has gunicorn in it. Also, both run_gunicorn and collectstatic work locally from within my venv. Why is this happening? I followed this: https://gist.github.com/joshfinnie/4046138 for my urls.py (note that my requirements.txt is generated from pip freeze > requirements.txt so it's up-to-date).

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Answer (score 3):

Is your Procfile in the same path as settings.py/manage.py or outside? I had a similar issue and move my Profile up one level in your project directory. This is how foreman executes on a normal Django project. However, I'm running it with wsgi.

Here's my Procfile

Procfile:
    web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; gunicorn your_project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT

Comment: It seems like "collectstatic" doesn't exist according to heroku logs. Also it can't import the wsgi module according to the heroku logs. My Procfile is in the same directory as manage.py and everything, just as Mezzanine generates it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have all of the required apps installed hence the lack of collectstatic and run_gunicorn.  Ensure that your requirements.txt has all necessary packages as required by Heroku.

My requirements.txt on a current Mezzanine project contains:

```
Cartridge==0.9.2
Django==1.6.2
Mezzanine==3.0.9
Pillow==2.3.1
bleach==1.4
boto==2.27.0
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.5
django-s3-storages-utils==0.1.0
django-storages==1.1.8
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
filebrowser-safe==0.3.2
future==0.9.0
grappelli-safe==0.3.7
gunicorn==18.0
html5lib==0.999
oauthlib==0.6.1
pisa==3.0.33
psycopg2==2.5.2
pystache==0.5.3
pytz==2014.2
requests==2.2.1
requests-oauthlib==0.4.0
six==1.6.1
static==1.0.2
tzlocal==1.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

[My Mezzanine on Heroku complete how-to is here https://web.archive.org/web/20161018191100/http://www.benhavilland.com/blog/deploying-mezzanine-on-heroku/](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018191100/http://www.benhavilland.com/blog/deploying-mezzanine-on-heroku//)